# Asynchronous Multiple Bitmap-to-Disk Operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, bitmap, save

I'm changing the way my program behaves, for now, it stores all `Bitmap` in the memory. This causes a serious memory usage. Around 500MB for 100 * 400x250px images.

This is my code (Now, saving all frames to the disk):

```
//Begin Iteration (In this case, a Timer.Tick event)

_graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, _sizeResolution, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
_listFrames.Add(String.Format("{0}{1}.bmp", _pathTemp, _frameCount));
_bitmap.Save(String.Format("{0}{1}.bmp", _pathTemp, _frameCount));

//End Iteration
```

The problem is that saving an image to the disk hangs a bit.

So my question is: **How to make a async saving function with less overhead possible?**

### What I'm Trying...

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {  });
//Nothing much fancy, no change at all.
```

and

```
Delegate.BeginInvoke(param, Callback, null);
```

### So... I was thinking about...

The producer is faster than the consumer. The producer can make bitmaps faster than the consumer can save.

While the producer creates the bitmaps, a consumer keeps saving and disposing the bitmap from the memory without synchrony. This way there is no need to call a `BeginInvoke()` or a `Backgroundworker.DoWork()` for each frame, reducing the overhead of creating new threads.

Comment: It sounds like you just want a background worker?

Comment: Yes, I want a background worker, but each frame captured need to be saved inside the iteration loop.